# Firebase with nodejs error

Tags: node.js, firebase

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
>       at Object. (/Users/jacob/node_modules/firebase/firebase.js:32:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/Users/jacob/nodetest/firebasetest.js:4:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)

when trying to require firebase with this single line of code:

```
var firebase = require("../node_modules/firebase/firebase")
```

according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

any hints?

Comment: That doc tells you to use `var firebase = require("firebase")`. The path should not be needed and may well explain the problem you're having (since the firebase module will try to pull in more dependencies).

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem.